# How to solve : $|3 x-2|<|x+1|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve :i have the following inequality involving absolute value in both sides ... what is the general method to solve?
thanks for help
$$|3 x-2|<|x+1|?$$

Comment: Please show your efforts

Comment: Hint: $|A| < B \implies -B < A < B$.

Comment: Do you seek solutions over $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb H$, or what?

Comment: It's the same as $(3x-2)^2<(x+1)^2$.

Comment: The first thing that I would do is to draw a graph. The solution is more or less immediate after that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918856/what-is-the-method-for-solving-the-inequality-x1-geq-2-x/2918859#2918859

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want solutions over $\Bbb R$, the condition is equivalent to$$0\gt(3x-2)^2-(x+1)^2=(4x-1)(2x-3),$$where we factorise using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. This positive-leading-coefficient quadratic is negative in between its roots, so the solution set is $\left(\frac14,\,\frac32\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the following cases:
$$x\geq \frac{2}{3}$$
$$-1\le x<\frac{2}{3}$$
$$x<-1$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Solve

$$
3x-2 < x+1
$$

and then solve

$$
3x-2 > -(x+1)
$$

to get an interval.

Answer (score 0):

Both $|3x-2|$ and $|x+1|$ are non-negative. So we have
\begin{align*}
&\;|3x-2|<|x+1|\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\; |3x-2|^2<|x+1|^2\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\; (3x-2)^2<(x+1)^2\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\; (2x-3)(4x-1)<0\\
\Longleftrightarrow &\;\frac14<x<\frac32
\end{align*}